# How can I do a negative regex match in batch?

Tags: regex, batch-file

This time, I am unable to create an if statement for my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977221/how-to-properly-set-a-variable-from-powershell-in-windows-batch-file)

I'm trying to check if the value is in this form: `^\d\d\.\d$`

Most of the time, it will. However, it is sometimes unavailable.

In other scripting languages, I can manage it, but I cannot, for some unknown reasons, figure out how to do it in batch.

So, it should be something like:

```
if not findstr /R "^\d\d\.\d$" %newvalue%
set newvalue=
```

If it's not `"^\d\d\.\d$"`, then set `newvalue` blank. This is only to blank `newvalue` when it is not found because it will give random results.

Can somebody help me out? What's the best way to do this `if` statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @npocmaka: I got this error message: FINDSTR: Cannot open 12.0

Comment: `FindStr` does not use standard regex, for digits it uses **`[0-9]`** and as **`.`** is a wildcard metacharacter, a literal **`.`** requires escaping with the **`\ `** character. Please open a Command Prompt window and enter **`FindStr /?`** to read the usage information. Also, please note that `FindStr` will return the entire line, not just a specific string within that line.

Comment: @Compo: I did, but I can't figure out how to implement an if statement while using FindStr. "^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]$" still gives me the same error message.

Comment: @Ricky, that's of absolutely no use to us, as we cannot see the command or string your running the `FindStr` command against. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53988684/edit), to include your code as it now stands. Please make sure before you do that, that your code follows the syntax as shown under the output from the usage information.

Comment: With your syntax above findstr expects `%newvalue%` to be file, not a string. You'll have to use echo: `Echo:%newvalue%|findstr "^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]$" >Nul 2>&1 &&(echo matched pattern)||(echo didn't match pattern)`

Comment: @LotPings: thank you, again! It worked flawlessly :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very good working solution posted by [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) is:

```
Echo:%newvalue%|findstr "^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]$" >Nul 2>&1 &&(echo matched pattern)||(echo didn't match pattern)
```

I suggest a little bit different single line solution:

```
echo:%newvalue%|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]\.[0123456789]$" >nul && (echo matched pattern) || (echo didn't match pattern)
```

Or easier readable and working for really any string value assigned to environment variable `newvalue`:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo:!newvalue!| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]\.[0123456789]$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Value does not match the regular expression pattern.
) else (
    echo Value matches the regular expression pattern.
)
endlocal
```

A colon is used between command `echo` and the string assigned to environment variable `newvalue` instead of a space to avoid that command **ECHO** outputs the current status of command echoing in case of `newvalue` is not defined at all.

The last solution uses [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to avoid that the command line with **ECHO** and **FINDSTR** does not work or does something completely different than it is written for if the string assigned to variable `newvalue` contains operators like `&<>|`.

It is important that there is no space left to redirection operator `|` which pipes output of command **ECHO** to the command **FINDSTR** as input because of this space character would be also output by command **ECHO** and the regular expression find would never be positive. A space right to `|` does not matter as last example demonstrates.

**FINDSTR** does not support `\d` as representation for **any digit**. It is necessary to specify the characters to match in a self-defined character class in square brackets. **FINDSTR** matches with `[0-9]` the characters `0123456789¹²³`. It is necessary to use `[0123456789]` to match just the characters `0123456789` without `¹²³`.

`.` means any character, except the dot is escaped with a backslash in which case it is interpreted as literal character.

A search string in `"..."` is interpreted by **FINDSTR** by default as regular expression string. But I think, it is always good to make use of `/L` or `/R` to make it 100% clear for **FINDSTR** and for every reader how the search string should be interpreted, as literal or as regular expression string.

**FINDSTR** exits with value `1` on no positive match on searched input character stream and `0` on at least one positive match. The exit code of **FINDSTR** can be evaluated as shown above and described in detail in [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

The output of **FINDSTR** on a positive match is of no interest and therefore redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `if /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) and DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) for the reason why using `:` after `echo` is often better than a space on output of a string read from a file or entered by a user.