# How to make this powershell command work inside a loop in batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Trying to find the difference. But when this powershell command is inside in the findstr, it fails. On its own, it returns the correct value. Also, without the loop, it returns the correct value.

```
echo:!newvalue!| findstr /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]\.[0123456789]$" >nul
  if errorlevel 1 (
    set newvalue=
  ) else (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (`powershell -nop -c "'{0:n1}' -f (%newvalue% - 12.0)"`) DO (SET difference=%%i)
    echo %difference%
  )
```

Can anyone figure out what I'm missing/did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly may be included in `%newvalue%`, _the code suggests from `00.0` to `99.9`, but that code was only a suggestion from @Mofi in their [unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989838) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53988684)_. It may therefore be that including a `For` loop with a call to `PowerShell` just to subtract an integer, i.e. `12`, from `%newvalue%` is a little heavy handed.

Comment: @Compo: first, checking if its \d\d\.\d. Next, doing a subtraction, -12.0 in this case. The powershell command line works on its own, but not inside this loop. I can't figure out why

Comment: @Ricky, I know what you're trying to do, I'm suggesting only that it may be a little over the top. What possible values are you expecting `%newvalue%` to hold?

Comment: @Compo: I'm expecting a low number each time (\d.\d). I need the decimal point

Comment: Your first question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53977221), suggested it was a date pattern, but as years, months and days can all exceed a single digit, I'm a little confused. My assumption is that the first two digits are the month, which would make the subtraction of `12` to make some sense. Your main issue is that you're jumping between powershell.exe and cmd.exe, and asking questions at each stage of your project. This could cause you issues and create an inefficient, hard to maintain script. Could you not just explain the task in its entirety, and provide all code to date?

Comment: @Compo: sorry for the confusion, but it has nothing to do with the date. Just reading a file and comparing stats. I was edit part by part to improve the outlook. Anyhow, everything is working fine with the help of you all!

Comment: Why could the entire thing not be done in either cmd.exe or powershell.exe. You said in your initial question that you didn't know how to retrieve the value in a batch file, but was shown how to do that. `Set` can be used to easily subtract `12.0` from `%newvalue%`. Because you have a known number of digits, `3`, and a known position for the decimal point, that decimal point can be removed, the calculation done and the decimal point be replaced again. Calling PowerShell will certainly hit the execution time, so if it could be avoided in such a simple way, I'd recommend doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Windows command processor replaces all environment variable references using syntax `%variable%` inside a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` already on parsing the command line using this command block. This means the command line `echo %difference%` inside **ELSE** branch command block of the **IF** command is modified by `cmd.exe` before command **IF** is executed at all. `%difference%` is replaced by current value of environment variable `difference` or an empty string in case of environment variable `difference` is not defined somewhere above the **IF** condition. In latter case `echo`  is the command line remaining after parsing the command block and therefore shows status of command echoing instead of the string value assigned to environment variable `difference` in the command line above. The solution with already enabled delayed environment variable expansion is using `echo !difference!` in **ELSE** command block.

A solution for this floating point subtraction without usage of PowerShell can be seen below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined NewValue goto Validate

:UserPrompt
set /P "NewValue=Enter value between 00.0 and 99.9: "

:Validate
echo:!NewValue!| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]\.[0123456789]$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 set "NewValue=" & goto UserPrompt

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%I in ("%NewValue%") do set "PreComma=%%I" & set "PostComma=%%J"
set /A Difference=1%PreComma% - 112
set "Difference=%Difference%.%PostComma%"
echo Difference is: %Difference%
endlocal
```

After validating that the string assigned to environment variable `NewValue` indeed consists of two digits, a point and one more digit as requested and expected and described at [How can I do a negative regex match in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989838/3074564), the floating point number string is split up on `.` into pre-comma and post-comma number strings.

The pre-comma number is subtracted by 12 using an arithmetic expression. But it must be taken into account that an integer number with a leading 0 is interpreted by `cmd.exe` on evaluation of the arithmetic expression as octal number. That is no problem for `00` to `07`. But `08` and `09` would be invalid octal numbers and so Windows command processor would use value `0` resulting in a wrong subtraction result if simply `set /A Difference=PreComma - 12` would have been used in batch file. The workaround is concatenating the string `1` with the pre-comma string to a number string in range `100` to `199` and subtract `112` to get the correct result.

The post-comma value does not need to be modified and so the `Difference` value is determined finally with concatenating the result of the arithmetic expression with the unmodified post-comma number string.

It is possible to get the `Difference` value also always with two digits by inserting following additional command lines above `echo Difference is: %Difference%`:

```
if %Difference:~0,1% == - (
    if %Difference:~2,1% == . set "Difference=-0%Difference:~1%"
) else (
    if %Difference:~1,1% == . set "Difference=0%Difference%"
)
```

This solution avoids also the problem that floating point result of `PowerShell` is formatted according to region and language settings. For example in Germany and Austria the **decimal symbol** is `,` and not `.` which means the subtraction result output by PowerShell for `15.3 - 12.0` is `3,3` and not `3.3`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically an answer, as you've already received and accepted one a perfectly good one.

It is just to allow you to visualise a method of taking the string from your file, splitting it at the decimal point and subtracting `12`, *from a whole number greater or equal to `12`, (see the accepted answer for whole numbers less than `12`)*, all without 'loops' or `PowerShell`

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Create a variable from the first line of your file
Set /P "newvalue="<"file.tmp"
Echo [%newvalue%]

Rem Exit if the string 'value' does not exist in '%newvalue%'
If "%newvalue%"=="%newvalue:*value=%" Exit /B

Rem ReSet the variable to everything after the string 'value'
Set "newvalue=%newvalue:*value=%"
Echo [%newvalue%]

Rem ReSet the variable to everything up to the first 'space' character
Set "newvalue=%newvalue: ="&:"%"
Echo [%newvalue%]

Rem ReSet the variable, removing the unneeded leading '=' character
Set "newvalue=%newvalue:~1%"
Echo [%newvalue%]

Rem Set a new variable to the whole number, i.e. everything up to the first '.' character
Set "whole=%newvalue:.="&:"%"
Echo [%whole%]

Rem Set a new variable to the decimal, i.e. everything after the '.' character
Set "decimal=%newvalue:*.=%"
Echo [%decimal%]

Rem Subtract 12 from the whole number
Set /A remainder=100+whole-112
Echo [%remainder%]

Rem ReJoin the variables to show the difference
Echo [%remainder%.%decimal%]

Pause
```

Obviously in your script proper, you'd only need:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set /P "newvalue="<"file.tmp"
If "%newvalue%"=="%newvalue:*value=%" Exit /B
Set "newvalue=%newvalue:*value=%"
Set "newvalue=%newvalue: ="&:"%"
Set "newvalue=%newvalue:~1%"
Set "whole=%newvalue:.="&:"%"
Set "decimal=%newvalue:*.=%"
Set /A remainder=100+whole-112
Echo %remainder%.%decimal%
Pause
```